# SQL apply different where condition (filter) for each group in table

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause

i have following SQL table A in my database:

```
index, group, foo
  1      A     2
  2      A     2
  3      A     0
  4      A     1
  5      B     2
  6      B     1
  7      C     1
```

There are few more groups and I need to write a query based on this filter table B. For each group in table A it's index should be equal or greater than index_egt from table B for the same group.

If the group is not listed in table B, the group won't be filtered.

```
index_egt, group
  3      A     
  5      B
```

Expected result:

```
index, group, foo
  3      A     0
  4      A     1
  5      B     2
  6      B     1
  7      C     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the A.index>=B.index_egt will handle cases where the group is listed in TableB and the B.index_egt IS NULL will handle cases where the group is not listed:

```
SELECT 
A.index,
A.group,
A.foo
FROM TableA AS A
LEFT JOIN TableB AS B ON A.group=B.group
WHERE A.index>=B.index_egt 
OR B.index_egt IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  a.*
from
  A a
left join
  B b ON b.group = a.group
where
  a.index >= b.index_egt OR b.index_egt IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I always like this trick with coalesce

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a_table_with_no_name a
LEFT JOIN b_table_with_no_name b ON b.group = a.group
WHERE a.index >= COALESCE(b.index_egt,a.index)
```